# Need help solving a question related to arithmetic progression with logarithm after it

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic-progressions

The question is as follows:

In the sequence,

$$
(a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}, ..., a_{9}, a_{10})
$$

There is a AP in which,

$$
a_2+a_9=243
$$

Resolve,

$$
\log_3(a_1+a_{10})^2
$$

I can do basic AP's and GP's without sweating, however, I really don't know how to answer this one.

Comment: Since it's arithmetic, then $a_1 + a_{10} = a_2 + a_9$. Remember that $a_2 = a_1 + d$ and $a_{10} = a_9 - d$, where $d$ is the common difference.

Comment: $\log_3{243}=5$

Comment: @KM101 That much I know, however, i don't know how to define the values of $a_1, a_2$ nor $a_9, a_{10}$

Comment: For clarification, in my previous comment, there's a typo: I meant $a_9 = a_{10} - d$. (Once adding $a_{1}$ and $a_{10}$, you add and subract $d$, so they cancel out. The actual value of $d$ isn't relevant.)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oooh, now I get it, Thanks a lot!

Comment: you don't have to know values for $a_1$  and for $a_{10}$ -- just for $a_1+a_{10}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yeah, I've got it now, I was confused when it came to the basics of it. I forgot that $a_1+a_{10}=a_2+a_9$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's an arithmetic progression, $a_1+a_{10}=a_2+a_9$,

so $\log_3(a_1+a_{10})^2=2\log_3(243)=2\times5=10$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If the difference for the progression is $d$, then
$$a_2+a_9 = \underbrace{a_2 -d}_{a_1}+\underbrace{d+a_9}_{a_{10}}$$